# "kubectl get nodes" shows only master not workers

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the document https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/ to try to create a kubernetes cluster with 3 vagrant ubuntu vm in my local mac. But I can only see the master by running "kubectl get nodes" in master node after "kubeadm join" successfully. After tried several possible ways googled from internet, still the same issue.

Here listed some information about my cluster:

> 3 vagrant virtual machines (ubuntu 16.04):
>   - (master) eth0: 10.0.2.15, eth1: 192.168.101.101
>   --> kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors Swap --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.101.101
>   - (worker1) eth0: 10.0.2.15, eth1: 192.168.101.102
>   --> kubeadm join 192.168.101.101:6443 --token *** --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:** --ignore-preflight-errors Swap
>   - (worker2) eth0: 10.0.2.15, eth1: 192.168.101.103
>   --> kubeadm join 192.168.101.101:6443 --token  **--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:*** --ignore-preflight-errors Swap

Any ideas on this?

Regards,
Jacky

#### screenshot for kubelet log

[image: screenshot for kubelet log]

[log-new-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHx7k.jpg)
[log-new-part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJfDW.jpg)

Comment: Can you post status and logs of kubelet service on worker node?

Comment: Output for "systemctl status kubelet":  kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-20 06:10:10 UTC; 2h 29min ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 4721 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 12
   Memory: 39.6M
      CPU: 2min 25.780s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service

Comment: Output for "journalctl -xeu kubelet": <br/>  pod_container_deletor.go:77] Container "ea4ba30fd23bf91cdce59a3e5402317bfeff1474600b8b3a68c06af2f3289f1c" not found in pod's containers....]  <br/> 4721 kubelet_node_status.go:377] Error updating node status, will retry: failed to patch status "{\"status\":{\"$setElementOrder/addresses\":[{\"type\":\"In
Jun 20 06:48:38 default-ubuntu-1604 kubelet[4721]: 9356b8610\",\"k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1\"],\"sizeBytes\":742472}],...

Answer (score 0):

your problem with default route on the salve node fix the routing table.

I use script like this to fix the routes after OS starup.

```
#!/bin/bash

if $( ip route |grep  -q '^default via 10.0.2.2 dev' ); then
        ip route delete default via  10.0.2.2
fi

if ! $( ip r |egrep -q '^default .* eth1'); then
        ip route add default via 192.168.15.1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried your proposal to change the routes as:  default via 192.168.101.1 dev eth1 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.101.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.101.102 . But the issue is still there. I have removed the env KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS from /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf in the slave node. No idea if it is related.

Comment: Do you have the firewall enabled on the servers? check master and slave.

Comment: Just checked. Both master and slave have firewall disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that any node [masters and workers] have unique hostname. After few hours just realize that my master and cloned VM's from master have same hostname **master**, after change my worker nodes hostname into **worker-node-01** and **worker-node-02** all works perfect.